# Resizing Silverlight container div makes Silverlight reload in Firefox

Tags: jquery, silverlight, firefox

wondering if anyone has found an easy fix for this.  It appears as though you cannot control the size of your Silverlight by using a width/height of 100% on the Silverlight object and then animating the container div height and width in FIrefox.  I was wondering if anyone has found a workaround for it.  Pretty frustrating, the following works fine in all browsers besides Firefox.

You can see when you click test in Firefox the Silverlight control disappears and the Silverlight object has to reload itself.  In other browsers it does not have to reload and just animates fine.  Why Firefox, why? Now I have to hate you.

```
UserControl x:Class="testFirefox.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Border BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Center" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>testFirefox</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#testSilverlight").click(function () {
                $("#silverlightControlHost").animate({ width: 700 }, 2000, 'swing');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost" style="height:300px; width: 300px;">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/testFirefox.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
        <div id="testSilverlight" style="height:50px; width:50px; border: 1px solid black;">
         TEST
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because jQuery animate changes the overflow of the container causing the silverlight to reload. Something similar might happen when you change the display or the position of the container on firefox.
I've solved this commenting the line 8266 of jQuery 1.6.4 (the line might be near on other versions after 1.5) uncompressed version which says 
    this.style.overflow = "hidden";

Hope this helps.

Marcos.